# Why 'cannot overwrite existing file'?

Tags: linux, filesystems

I try to write to a file `date > file` but Linux says

> 'cannot overwrite existing file'.

I tried `chmod 755` but still cannot write to the file. What should I do?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you are running bash, the `noclobber` option has been set. Use `>|` if you want to temporarily override this.

Comment: How to redirect both stderr and stdout and temporarily override noclobber at the same time? I tried `&>|` without luck.

Answer (score 7):

Turn off noclobber in current shell session:

```
set +o noclobber
```

Turn on noclobber in current shelll session:

```
set -o noclobber
```

See all bash settings:

```
set -o
```

References:
https://www.victordodon.com/to-clobber-or-to-noclobber/
https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that the file was set as immutable with `chattr`. It's rarely used, but it's a realistic possibility. In that case:

```
chattr -i [filename]
```

... should be able to remove that attribute.

Comment: Writing to an "immutable" file would result in "Operation not permitted.".

Answer (score 2):

If you 're running **oh-my-bash** you can change this behavior in:

```
/home/user/.oh-my-bash/lib/shopt.sh
```

You comment out the following:

```
#set -o noclobber
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Go to your home folder
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to show hidden files
3. Check whether any of the folders are locked
4. Right click on the folder then click "properties". In that click "permissions".
5. Under owner, change folder access to "create and delete files."
6. Click "Apply Permissions to Enclosed files"

If you cannot see any locked folders then select all folders and do the above

Comment: Somehow, I don't expect this to work in every case ;-) Hint: some people don't use the same DE as you do, or even any GUI at all.